# agregar texto debajo del código de barras en php libreria picqer/php-barcode-generator

Tags: php, composer

soy nuevo en la comunidad y no había tenido necesidad de escribir alguna pregunta en concreta ya que todas se resolvían con otras preguntas que ya estaban planteadas.

Mi situación es la siguiente estoy creando un generador de codigos de barras usando composer y una liberia llamada [picqer/php-barcode-generator](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator)

la cual me permite generar los códigos de barras en diferentes formatos, ya sea code128, code39 etc.

me genera los códigos de barras sin problema, pero no genera los dígitos que van abajo del código de barras. lo que de seo es que se vea de la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero solo me genera de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya intente con imagestring y con imagettftext pero no veo resultado o cambio alguno ya que no logro agregar el texto al código de barras.

comparto mi código php el cual funciona para que al momento de poner el enlace con los dígitos que deseo generar lo genere y no lo guarda en ningún lado solo lo genera cada que se ingresa la url con los dígitos.

````
```
<?php
 # Si no hay parámetro, salir

 if(empty($_GET["c"])) exit("No proporcionaste el texto en la URL");

 # Incluimos el autoload
 require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

 # Indicamos que usaremos el namespace de BarcodeGeneratorPNG
 use Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG;

 # Crear generador
 $generador = new BarcodeGeneratorPNG();

 # Ajustes
 $texto = $_GET["c"];
 $tipo = $generador::TYPE_CODE_128;

 $imagen = $generador->getBarcode($texto, $tipo, 2, 81);

 header("Content-type: image/png");

 echo $imagen;
```
````

ese es mi código funcional que genera los códigos de barras no le eh agregado  nada mas para que puedan testearlo por si solo y vean como funciona para que puedan ayudarme con agregar el texto.